# NLTK chunking grammar with backreference

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nltk

I try to use NLTK RegexpParser to extract noungroups. The grammar (not English :)) needs regex backreference, just like in regular expressions. Is it possible?

```
from nltk.chunk import RegexpParser

grammar = '''
    NP: {<NN(.*)><CC><NN\1>} # this gives error
        {<NN(.*)><CC><NN$1>} # this has no effect
    '''
chunker = RegexpParser(grammar)
```

For example it would be a match:
*"NN+PLURAL CC NN+PLURAL"*
but this wouldn't:
*"NN+PLURAL CC NN+ACCUSATIVE"*

My question: does nltk.RegexpParser have regex backreference option?